# How to distinguish virtual MAC address and physical MAC address

Tags: go, server, mac-address

I want to generate an unique id using MAC address, but there are  virtual MAC addresses and physical MAC addresses in a server through `net.Interfaces()`. How can I distinguish them? I do not want to use the virtual ones.

Here is what I get using `net.Interfaces()`

```
[[
{1 65536 lo  up|loopback} 
{2 1450 eth0 fa:16:3e:12:39:9c up|broadcast|multicast} 
{3 1500 docker0 02:42:b4:9d:fb:54 up|broadcast|multicast} 
{4 1500 br-dbabe92ec60c 02:42:e3:7f:96:13 up|broadcast|multicast} 
{6 1500 veth4bb5809 e6:a3:38:2f:f7:e4 up|broadcast|multicast} 
{8 1500 vethcada9d2 16:8c:c9:37:8d:76 up|broadcast|multicast} 
{10 1500 veth1e10eaa da:37:f9:9a:1d:10 up|broadcast|multicast}
]]
```

I can not find the differences between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like below should work.  The comment in the code explains why as does this [faq](https://macaddress.io/faq/what-are-a-universal-address-and-a-local-administered-address).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
)

func main(){

    ifaces, err := net.Interfaces()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(0)
    }

    for _, iface := range ifaces {      
        // If the second least significant bit of the first octet of the MAC address is 1,
        // then it's a locally administered address so we omit it.
        // If HardwareAddr is nil, it's a loopbook, so omit.
        if (iface.HardwareAddr==nil) || (iface.HardwareAddr[0]&2 == 2) {
            continue
        }
        fmt.Println(iface)
    }

}
```

I'm sure you have a reason you want to use the MAC for a uuid, but I'd be remiss if I did not mention you may want to look at doing something like UUIDv4.

Comment: If so, all of my MAC addresses in the server are not real, they are virtual addresses, are they? In fact I am a little confuse about this, could a server have no real MAC address?

Comment: The server is virtually deployed through `OpenStack`, I do not know if this is the reason why it does not have the real MAC address.

Comment: If your code is running in a virtualization environment and the VM is not configured for PCI passthrough, then all network interfaces will be "virtual" as well.

Comment: This doesn't seem to always be true. e.g VMWare interfaces MAC starts with 00:50:56, or I have the MAC of an OpenVPN interface that starts with 00:FF, in both cases the bit is not set to 1

Comment: This will exclude wlan

Answer (score 1):

If the hardware devices are registered with https://macvendors.com/ then you can use their API

I added another mac address to your data as none of the above seemed to be recognised as "real" hardware

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "net/http"
        "net/url"
        "io"
        "time"
)

type idata struct {
        index int
        mtu   int
        name  string
        mac   string
        flags string
}

func main() {

        data := []idata{
                {1, 65536, "lo", "", "up|loopback"},
                {2, 1450, "eth0", "", "up|broadcast|multicast"},
                {3, 1500, "docker0", "02:42:b4:9d:fb:54", "up|broadcast|multicast"},
                {4, 1500, "br-dbabe92ec60c", "02:42:e3:7f:96:13", "up|broadcast|multicast"},
                {6, 1500, "veth4bb5809", "e6:a3:38:2f:f7:e4", "up|broadcast|multicast"},
                {8, 1500, "vethcada9d2", "16:8c:c9:37:8d:76", "up|broadcast|multicast"},
                {10, 1500, "veth1e10eaa", "da:37:f9:9a:1d:10", "up|broadcast|multicast"},
                {11, 1500, "en8", "00:e0:4c:36:01:d4", "up|broadcast|multicast"},
        }

        for _, iv := range data {
                // skip items (like localhost) with no mac address
                if iv.mac == "" {
                   continue
                }
                // url encode the mac address
                mac := url.QueryEscape(iv.mac)              
                resp, err := http.Get("https://api.macvendors.com/" + mac)
                defer resp.Body.Close()
                if err != nil {
                        panic(err)
                }
                
                body, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
                fmt.Println(iv.mac)
                fmt.Println(string(body))
                fmt.Println("-----------------")
                // sleep to stop the API rate limit being exceeded
                time.Sleep( 5 * time.Second)
        }
}
```

Comment: This is pretty interesting as well.  Nice!